# How to run retrofit source code?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, retrofit, retrofit2

I am interested in the Retrofit source code.

https://github.com/square/retrofit

But I found nowhere telling me about how to run the source code.

I imported the source code either in IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio both from the root directory of the source code and the directory 'sample'.

But none of them can run successfully.

There are several pom.xml files.

Anyone know how to run these codes?

**EDIT:** 
The comment said that it is a library and cannot be run. We only import this library when I use it in an android project using build.gradle to import it.

So my question is:

1. How to use maven to import it?
2. How the maintainer of this library maintain this library, I think it is at least debuggable and can break a point. There should be some test case to test this library, how to run the test case?
3. How to read the source code?

Comment: Why don't you just open an issue on github?

Comment: Retrofit is a library, you do not "run" it directly but use it in your application and then run your application.

Comment: You could import it as maven project and then run classes using green triangle in left gutter

Answer (score 2):

The Retrofit source code is available in Maven Central :
https://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.squareup.retrofit2%22%20AND%20a%3A%22retrofit%22 (sources.jar).

If you use Maven, it will automatically be downloaded in Android Studio if you explore a class.

I used this library in one of my Android project : https://github.com/ghusta/android-docker-search !

To import it in Android add something like that in `app/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0'
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to include the jcenter() Maven repo (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html#top-level).